# Ofstream not creating txt file

Tags: c++

I am using Devcpp 5.11 whenever i erase the '.txt' code creating a file but i cant create a text file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){    
    ofstream newFile("file.txt");
    newFile.open("file.txt");
    newFile << "Hello, world!";
    newFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code generally looks correct. When you supply a file name to the ofstream constructor [it calls open() for you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream). You then need to check if the open() operation was successful with [is_open()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open). If is_open() returns false then perhaps your program doesn’t have sufficient permissions to write a file in the working directory.

Note: You can get equivalent behavior to is_open() by calling the [boolean cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) of ios_base like so: `if (!newFile) { /* error occurred */ }`. This might be more idiomatic.

Comment: I tried but it returns false so as you say i think i dont have permissions because i tried the example codes for ofstream it didnt worked.

Comment: What OS? Any atypical file system setup?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: What is your working directory? Is it privileged in any way? You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd to verify if you’re uncertain. If you’re executing from an IDE like Visual Studio it might not be where you expect.

Comment: I am just using dev c++ here is my working directory:
C:\Users\berke\Desktop\Projects\fstream.exe

Comment: Try printing out errno after the open operation fails. It might reveal more information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-constants

Comment: Also, are you sure that’s your working directory rather than simply the path to the executable? The path to the executable might not be the same as the path of the working directory. The working directory string shouldn’t be a file, it should be a folder.

Comment: I will check the path again and i used errno it says "cannot open output file fstream.exe: Permission denied"

Comment: I think your working directory might include the executable file name for some reason. In the Dev C++ project properties there is likely a way to change it. You want it to be a directory, not a file. Perhaps “ C:\Users\berke\Desktop\Projects\”. I don’t use Windows or Dev C++, though, so I’m unsure how to provide further assistance. I can confidently tell you it’s a configuration or filesystem issue, not a C++ issue, though. You might try running your executable directly from the command line .\fstream.exe as a sanity check. If that works, it’s a Dev C++ configuration issue.

Comment: I don't know why but i did it. I just uninstall my free antivirus program and restarted my pc. Thanks for your effort again.